# How to connect Spring-data-neo4j to embedded neo4j server?

Tags: java, spring-boot, neo4j, spring-data-neo4j, neo4j-embedded

I'm failing to combine Spring Data Neo4j and embedded neo4j server in one app. I've used them separately, but I can't make them work together.
Also, I haven't found guide on how to use them together anywhere.

### Starting points

A good base for MRE of Spring-data-neo4j can be found here: [gs-accessing-data-neo4j](https://github.com/spring-guides/gs-accessing-data-neo4j/tree/main/complete).

Clues on how to run embedded Neo4J server can be found here:

- [neo4j: Embedding Neo4j in your Java application](https://neo4j.com/docs/java-reference/current/java-embedded/setup/)
- [baeldung: A Guide to Neo4J with Java](https://www.baeldung.com/java-neo4j)

### Sample Project

Combining these sources, I've created this project:

`./pom.xml`:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.2</version>
        <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>accessing-data-neo4j-complete</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>accessing-data-neo4j-complete</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-neo4j</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.neo4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>neo4j</artifactId>
            <version>5.10.0</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

`.\src\main\java\myapp\AccessingDataNeo4jApplication.java`:

```java
package myapp;

import java.io.File;
import java.time.Duration;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

import org.neo4j.configuration.GraphDatabaseSettings;
import org.neo4j.cypherdsl.core.renderer.Configuration;
import org.neo4j.cypherdsl.core.renderer.Dialect;
import org.neo4j.dbms.api.DatabaseManagementService;
import org.neo4j.dbms.api.DatabaseManagementServiceBuilder;
import org.neo4j.graphdb.GraphDatabaseService;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;

import org.springframework.boot.CommandLineRunner;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.data.neo4j.repository.config.EnableNeo4jRepositories;

import static org.neo4j.configuration.GraphDatabaseSettings.DEFAULT_DATABASE_NAME;

@SpringBootApplication
@EnableNeo4jRepositories
public class AccessingDataNeo4jApplication {

    private final static Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(AccessingDataNeo4jApplication.class);

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        SpringApplication.run(AccessingDataNeo4jApplication.class, args);
        System.exit(0);
    }
    
    @Bean
    public Configuration cypherDslConfiguration() {
        return Configuration.newConfig().withDialect(Dialect.NEO4J_5).build();
    }

    @Bean
    public DatabaseManagementService databaseManagementService() {
        DatabaseManagementService managementService = new 
            DatabaseManagementServiceBuilder(new File("target/mydb").toPath())
                .setConfig(GraphDatabaseSettings.transaction_timeout, Duration.ofSeconds( 60 ) )
                .build();
        log.info("managementService created: {}",managementService);
        registerShutdownHook(managementService);
        return managementService;
    }

    @Bean
    public GraphDatabaseService graphDatabaseService(DatabaseManagementService managementService) {
        // managementService.createDatabase("mydb");
        GraphDatabaseService graphDb = managementService.database(DEFAULT_DATABASE_NAME);
        log.info("graphDb.isAvailable: {}",graphDb.isAvailable());  //true
        return graphDb;
    }
    
    private static void registerShutdownHook( final DatabaseManagementService managementService ) {
        Runtime.getRuntime().addShutdownHook( new Thread() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                managementService.shutdown();
            }
        } );
    }   

    @Bean
    CommandLineRunner demo(PersonRepository personRepository) {
        return args -> {

            personRepository.deleteAll();

            Person greg = new Person("Greg");
            Person roy = new Person("Roy");
            Person craig = new Person("Craig");

            List<Person> team = Arrays.asList(greg, roy, craig);

            log.info("Before linking up with Neo4j...");

            team.stream().forEach(person -> log.info("\t" + person.toString()));

            personRepository.save(greg);
            personRepository.save(roy);
            personRepository.save(craig);

            greg = personRepository.findByName(greg.getName());
            greg.worksWith(roy);
            greg.worksWith(craig);
            personRepository.save(greg);

            roy = personRepository.findByName(roy.getName());
            roy.worksWith(craig);
            // We already know that roy works with greg
            personRepository.save(roy);

            // We already know craig works with roy and greg

            log.info("Lookup each person by name...");
            team.stream().forEach(person -> log.info(
                    "\t" + personRepository.findByName(person.getName()).toString()));

            List<Person> teammates = personRepository.findByTeammatesName(greg.getName());
            log.info("The following have Greg as a teammate...");
            teammates.stream().forEach(person -> log.info("\t" + person.getName()));
        };
    }

}
```

`.\src\main\java\myapp\Person.java`:

```java
package myapp;

import java.util.*;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;
import org.springframework.data.neo4j.core.schema.*;

@Node
public class Person {

    @Id @GeneratedValue 
    private Long id;

    private String name;

    private Person() {
        
    };

    public Person(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    
    @Relationship(type = "TEAMMATE")
    public Set<Person> teammates;

    public void worksWith(Person person) {
        if (teammates == null) {
            teammates = new HashSet<>();
        }
        teammates.add(person);
    }

    public String toString() {
        return this.name + "'s teammates => "
            + Optional.ofNullable(this.teammates).orElse(
                    Collections.emptySet()).stream()
                        .map(Person::getName)
                        .collect(Collectors.toList());
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```

`.\src\main\java\myapp\PersonRepository.java`:

```java
package myapp;

import java.util.List;
import org.springframework.data.neo4j.repository.Neo4jRepository;

public interface PersonRepository extends Neo4jRepository<Person, Long> {
    Person findByName(String name);
    List<Person> findByTeammatesName(String name);
}
```

### Sample Project execution

`mvn clean spring-boot:run` results in these exceptions being thrown:

```
INFO 8164 --- [           main] o.neo4j.driver.internal.DriverFactory    : Direct driver instance 1068773063 created for server address localhost:7687
ERROR 8164 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application run failed
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to execute CommandLineRunner
Caused by: org.springframework.transaction.TransactionSystemException: Could not open a new Neo4j session: Unable to connect to localhost:7687, ensure the database is running and that there is a working network connection to it.
Caused by: io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel$AnnotatedConnectException: Connection refused: no further information: localhost/127.0.0.1:7687
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: no further information
INFO 8164 --- [           main] o.neo4j.driver.internal.InternalDriver   : Closing driver instance 1068773063
INFO 8164 --- [           main] o.n.d.i.async.pool.ConnectionPoolImpl    : Closing connection pool towards localhost:7687
```

Comment: You may need to [open a Bolt connector and enable it](https://neo4j.com/docs/java-reference/current/java-embedded/bolt/) in your embedded instance. I have never tried this, especially when running a Spring app, but hopefully this info is helpful.

Comment: @cybersam, thank you, it was very helpful. I've lost so much time on this matter. I wonder where I should have found out about this. Docs section you've provided is so easy to overlook. I have a feeling SDN docs also should mention it.

Comment: You can [report that SDN documentation issue](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-neo4j#reporting-issues).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As [cybersam](https://stackoverflow.com/users/974731/cybersam) pointed out, Bolt connector should be opened on embedded instance. This page of documentation shows how to do it:
https://neo4j.com/docs/java-reference/current/java-embedded/bolt/

1. Add neo4j-bolt dependency to pom.xml:

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.neo4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>neo4j-bolt</artifactId>
    <version>5.10.0</version>
</dependency>
```

2. To `DatabaseManagementService` object creation add lines configuring `BoltConnector`:

```java
DatabaseManagementService managementService = new 
            DatabaseManagementServiceBuilder(new File("target/mydb").toPath())
                .setConfig(GraphDatabaseSettings.transaction_timeout, Duration.ofSeconds( 60 ) )
                .setConfig( BoltConnector.enabled, true )
                .setConfig( BoltConnector.listen_address, new SocketAddress( "localhost", 7687 ) )
                .build();
```

P.S. Same question, more detailed answer: [Spring Boot embedded neo4j for demo purposes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77571107/spring-boot-embedded-neo4j-for-demo-purposes)