# Spring Boot neo4j

Tags: spring, neo4j

I want to use the built-in neo4j. I know that neo4j has a built-in neo4j driver for java, but it is not supported by `spring data neo4j`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are asking about how to use embedded neo4j in Spring Data Neo4j application, - indeed it is possible, even though officially is [not supported](https://gist.github.com/michael-simons/d3137f64ac0b13713fae8e7e1a69367e?permalink_comment_id=4756611#gistcomment-4756611) (I wonder where it is officially proclaimed).

This is how it can be done:

1. Add neo4j to dependencies:

```xml
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.neo4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>neo4j</artifactId>
        <version>5.13.0</version>
</dependency>
```

2. Add these beans to your Spring Boot configuration class:

```java
@Bean
    public Configuration cypherDslConfiguration() {
        return Configuration.newConfig().withDialect(Dialect.NEO4J_5).build();
    }

//https://neo4j.com/docs/java-reference/current/java-embedded/setup/
@Bean
public DatabaseManagementService databaseManagementService() {
    DatabaseManagementService managementService = new 
        DatabaseManagementServiceBuilder(new File("target/mydb").toPath())
            .setConfig(GraphDatabaseSettings.transaction_timeout, Duration.ofSeconds( 60 ) )
            .setConfig( BoltConnector.enabled, true )
            .setConfig(BoltConnector.encryption_level, BoltConnector.EncryptionLevel.DISABLED)
            .build();
    
    registerShutdownHook(managementService);
    return managementService;
}

@Bean
public GraphDatabaseService graphDatabaseService(DatabaseManagementService managementService) {
    GraphDatabaseService graphDb =
        managementService.database(GraphDatabaseSettings.DEFAULT_DATABASE_NAME);
    log.info("Neo4j database Embedded instance is available: {}", graphDb.isAvailable());
    return graphDb;
}
private static void registerShutdownHook(final DatabaseManagementService managementService) {
    Runtime.getRuntime().addShutdownHook(new Thread() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            managementService.shutdown();
        }
    });
}
```

3. Annotate your Spring Boot `@SpringBootApplication` with `@EnableNeo4jRepositories`.
4. SDN repositories now will work.

Fully working example can be found [in this Gist](https://gist.github.com/Podbrushkin/54518ad6c4835706fd3344f01ea6acc9),  place those files in correct subdirectories and execute `mvn clean spring-boot:run`, you will see repositories are working. Application will break only if you will enable HttpConnector.

I hope this is what you've asked for.

duplicate: [How to connect Spring-data-neo4j to embedded neo4j server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76901420/how-to-connect-spring-data-neo4j-to-embedded-neo4j-server)